# Why does sudo opens scripts with /bin/sh?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I have a script that needs sudo permissions and needs to be run with `/bin/bash` on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

If I run it while logged in as root (or any other user) it opens with `/bin/bash` as expected, however when I run the script with `sudo` it opens with `/bin/sh` no matter what user I'm logged in as.

I've checked `/etc/passwd` and I see `/bin/bash` is the default shell for root. `$SHELL` is defined as `/bin/bash` as well.

I won't be the only one using the script, so I can't rely on people using `sudo -i` to run it.

Where is the sudo shell defined? How can I change it?

Comment: Have you tried setting the shell using a #! line in the script?

Comment: Add to your script as first line : `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention I already set the shell that way. It didn't help. I'll edit the question

Comment: I just double-checked, I did have `#!/bin/bash` in the script but not as the first line! I had some comments about the script beforehand, old python habits I guess.
I've changed their order and the script opens with bash! Thanks. 
I can't upvote your comments :/

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Okay, thank you.
@DavidPostill can you please reopen my question so I can answer it? I don't want to do an empty edit.

Comment: @stavmeir Done.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I documented the script *before* the `#!/bin/bash` line, so the shebang wasn't the first line in the script.